# Committee Selection Probability Question (AS-Level)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

There are $15$ people from Swansea, $12$ from Wolverhampton and $10$ from Aberystwyth. A committee is to be made of at least $5$ people from Swansea and $2$ from anywhere else. The committee will only form if at least 5 people from Swansea are on it. What is the probability that the committee is entirely from Swansea (i.e. all $7$ people on the committee are from Swansea) ?

The way I worked it out was by writing out all of the possible combinations:
$$^{15}C_7 +\left(^{15}C_6 \times ^{12}C_1\right) + \left(^{15}C_6 \times ^{10}C_1\right) + \left(^{15}C_5 \times ^{10}C_1 \times ^{12}C_1\right) + \left(^{15}C_5 \times ^{10}C_2\right) + \left(^{15}C_5 \times ^{12}C_2\right)~.$$ This equals $810,238$. $($Note: $^{15}C_7$ means $15$ choose $7~)$

I then did $^{15}C_7$ divided by $810,238$ and I got $0.79\%~$.
I don’t understand why some people think you only need to focus on the last two positions, as a committee would form if the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th and 6th people were from Swansea. I know I must be wrong somewhere in my reasoning here so if you could point out where I would be thankful.

I was wondering if the method shown above is even the correct method and if there is a quicker way of working it all out (if it’s correct).

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Take a look at [How to ask a good question at Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). To avoid downvotes and closing you should add your own efforts to the question by means of an edit (not a comment), and tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct.  As for a faster way, you can group everybody from Wolverhampton and Aberystwyth together in the from anywhere else property.  Therefore, the probability that all seven committee members are from Swansea is
$$\frac{\dbinom{15}{7}}{\dbinom{15}{7} + \dbinom{15}{6}\dbinom{22}{1} + \dbinom{15}{5}\dbinom{22}{2}}$$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your answer is correct. To my understanding, the committee is *only* formed if there are at least 5 people from Swansea. This means that, in any other case, a committee is not formed.

Since the question asks what is the chance that a committee is entirely from Swansea, you have to assume that a committee is formed, and thus at least 5 people are from Swansea. Therefore, you only need to examine the remaining two positions:
$$
\left(\frac{10}{32}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{9}{31}\right) = 0.090725806,
$$
or, in your notation:
$$
\frac{10 \choose 2}{{10 \choose 2} + {10 \choose 1}\cdot{22 \choose 1} + {22 \choose 2}} = 0.090725806.
$$

Therefore the answer, in my interpretation of the question, is $\sim 9\%$.